# Can require.js automatically determine baseURL?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Say that I'm on the url: http://example.com . My baseURL for loading javascripts is 
'js' which means, example.com/js/

If I simply supply "js" as the baseURL on http://example.com , I think that it will work.

However, if the user is on example.com/signup/process or example.com/projects/view/55 , and the baseUrl is supplied as simply "js", will require.js be able to understand that it refers to example.com/js and not to example.com/projects/view/55/js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried supplying "/js" ?

Thanks

Comment: I've not tried anything yet, I'm just wondering if it will work on different urls or not. If I'm on example.com/signup/process , and I supply `/js`, will require.js treat this as `example.com/js` or `example.com/signup/process/js`